# how can i increase OS FS on CentOS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, operating-system, sysadmin

we have CentOS server installed on 83GB FS size while the OS disk size is 480gb

how can we increase the FS to use the whole disk (sda, 480gb)?

```
[root@server ~]# df -kh
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg01-lvroot   83G   14G   65G  18% /
devtmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.9G   17M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                488M   98M  355M  22% /boot
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0

sda               8:0    0  480G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 99.5G  0 part
  ├─vg01-lvroot 253:0    0 83.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg01-lvswap 253:1    0   16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]

[root@server ~]# vgs
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
vg01   1   2   0 wz--n- <99.50g    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend the volume group vg01 and after that the logical volume lvroot. You can check out how to do it using vgextend and pvextend commands. Be sure to extend the filesystem after using resize2fs.